# exp() returns a list of zeros in R

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a Gaussian fit for my data. However, my code returns a list of zeros. After isolating and running each component of the equation, I determined that the problem is the exp() function.

```
AbsG = AbsMax52*exp((-4*log(2))*((((WvLnV- 
WvLnMax52)^2))/(bandWidth52)))
```

AbsMax52, WvLnMax52, and bandWidth52 are all integers.
WvLnV is a vector with 1301 entries.

Can anyone explain why AbsG is a 1301 long vector of 0s and what I could do to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: We need to see your data to give a decent answer, but most likely `range((-4*log(2))*((((WvLnV- 
WvLnMax52)^2))/(bandWidth52)))` returns relatively large negative numbers. E.g., `exp(-800)` is seen as 0.

Comment: My WvLn vector is from 200 to 1500, so the values within exp get pretty large. Is there any way to work around it? I don't know of another way around using the exp function...

Comment: It's impossible for us to say if there is another way since we don't know what it is exactly that you are doing. A common trick is to take logs, though.